# Using XML datatype with LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I want to store an xml file in my database using the XML datatype. Currently the property of the entity is XElement. I set this to a Xelement and debugging i can see that its set correctly on the entity however it dosent save when I submit changes.

Is what I want to do possible? Should i change the default mapping?

Answer (score 2):

See http://conficient.wordpress.com/2008/08/11/linq-to-sql-faq-xml-columns-in-sql/

and [Linq-to-SQL With XML Database Fields -- Why does this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689772/linq-to-sql-with-xml-database-fields-why-does-this-work)

You need to new up a new XElement with the changes for linq to sql to update the field.