# Cannot update SQL Server XML column from F#

Tags: xml, f#, sql-update, sql-server-2012

I could not find anything on the [query expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh225374%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) page that answered my question.  In short, I can update any SQL Server data column except those that are of `type XML`.  The sample code below differs from my actual code only in the names of the columns.

```
let update () : unit =
    let dbctx = DBSchema.GetDataContext() // The DBSchema type has already been defined as a SimpleDataContextType
    query {
        for row in dbctx.My_Table do
        select row
    }
    |> Seq.iter (fun s ->
        s.IntCol <- 10 // Works
        s.VarcharCol <- "Varchar value" // Works
        /////
        s.XmlCol.Add(new XElement(XName.Get "ChildNode")) // Does not work!
        /////
        let x = s.XmlCol
        x.Add(new Xelement(XName.Get "ChildNode"))
        s.XmlCol <- x // Still does not work!
        /////
        dbctx.DataContext.SubmitChanges())
```

The `XML column` in SQL Server never changes.  It remains the same, even when the other columns change as indicated.

Is there a different recommended way to update `SQL Server XML columns` from F#?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is any exception thrown?

Comment: No, none whatsoever.  It's like the program has been talking to my girlfriend, and has learnt to ignore me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you create a new `XElement` instance, *reference equality* still holds and Linq-to-SQL can't detect changes in `XmlCol`.

The following example should work as expected

```ml
let x = s.XmlCol
x.Add(new XElement(XName.Get "ChildNode"))
s.XmlCol <- new XElement(x)
```

The behavior is confusing when you think in terms of default *structural equality* in F#.

You can read a similar thread [Linq-to-SQL With XML Database Fields -- Why does this work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689772/linq-to-sql-with-xml-database-fields-why-does-this-work) for another explanation.